# Trouble understanding call of method within an instance/declaration

Tags: javascript, oop, variables, callback, instantiation

I'm taking an online web development course. I've come across some code that is confusing me. Within the *index.js* file there is a variable titled *defaultCardList* which instantiates a new instance of *Section* class. However, before the declaration is finished, within the *renderer* property, the *defaultCardList* variable is used to call the *setItem* method.

How is it possible to call the method from the *defaultCardList* variable before it's completely declared?

```
const defaultCardList = new Section({
  data: items,
  renderer: (item) => {
    const card = new DefaultCard(item, ".default-card");
    const cardElement = card.generateCard();
    defaultCardList.setItem(cardElement); //How can this be called before its completion?
  }
}, cardListSelector);
```

Comment: It's inside the `renderer` function. Which is not called until after the `defaultCardList` is initialised (or else the code would indeed break).

Comment: It's *not* called before it's completely declared. The body of that method won't be executed until you have the instance, at which point it has been completely decorated.

Comment: I believe I understand it a bit more. I guess the use/syntax of the defaultCardList confuses me, especially when thinking about what happens to it when it enters the Section class.

Thanks for clarifying. :v)

Comment: `defaultCardList` never enters the `Section` constructor. The value that is passed is (an object with) a function, and that function [closes over the `defaultCardList` variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1048572) (not the value). Maybe also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52879220/1048572)