# Is there a way to cleanly create a promise that resolves after left mouse up or down?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

In my client code, I have

```
const whatMouseDid = await mouseDoesSomething()
```

with the latter function looking like:

```
async mouseDoesSomething() {
    const mouseUp = (resolve) => {
        const handler = (evt) => {
            if (evt.button === 0)
                resolve("up")
        }
        return handler
    }
    const mouseDown = (resolve) => {
        const handler = (evt) => {
            if (evt.button === 0)
                resolve("down")
        }
        return handler
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp(resolve))
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown(resolve))
    })
}
```

Which is already a bit more convoluted than I'd prefer, but still manageable. However, there's a problem - the listeners are never removed. And because I need to pass in a reference to `Promise.resolve`, I can't `removeEventListener` easily. The only way I can think to do this is to keep a mutable list of handlers and the events, targets, etc they are assigned to, and in the handler function(s), iterate over that list and remove attached handlers. The optional param `{once: true}` also won't work because I don't resolve if the button clicked is not the one I want.

This all feels super convoluted, and makes me think I'm just missing the obvious easy way to do this; am I? Or is it really this much of nuisance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And because I need to pass in a reference to Promise.resolve, I can't removeEventListener easily. The only way I can think to do this is to keep a mutable list

Why so complicated? You create functions in the promise executor, just reference them.

```
mouseDoesSomething() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const mouseUphandler = evt => {
            if (evt.button === 0) {
                resolve("up")
                document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpHandler)
                document.removeEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownHandler)
            }
        }
        const mouseDownhandler = evt => {
            if (evt.button === 0) {
                resolve("down")
                document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpHandler)
                document.removeEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownHandler)
            }
        }
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpHandler)
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownHandler)
    })
}
```

Surely that's lots of code duplication, but you can abstract this again by creating the handlers dynamically - you just need to do it in the scope where the two handlers are declared:

```
mouseDoesSomething() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const makeHandler = dir => evt => {
            if (evt.button === 0) {
                resolve(dir)
                document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpHandler)
                document.removeEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownHandler)
            }
        }
        const mouseUphandler = makeHandler("up")
        const mouseDownhandler = makeHandler("down")
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpHandler)
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownHandler)
    })
}
```

Comment: That is better :) I always expect that I need names to be defined before I can use them, so I discarded similar ideas when working through it on my own.

Comment: That's the [magic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52880419/1048572) of [hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32475965/1048572) :-) I couldn't write code without it.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a helper function to call when you resolve your function:

```
mouseDoesSomething() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const mouseUp = (evt) => {
      if (evt.button === 0) resolveAndRemove("up");
    };
    const mouseDown = (evt) => {
      if (evt.button === 0) resolveAndRemove("down");
    };

    function resolveAndRemove(val) {
      document.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp);
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);
      resolve(val);
    }

    document.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp);
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);
  });
}
```

Also, since you're not using `await`, you don't need to mark the function as `async`.

Comment: Ah, that's not bad - I thought I couldn't reference a function before it was declared, but I guess that's not the case.

Answer (score 2):

Previous answers are fine, just a 2 cents answer for the (close) future:

`EventTarget.addEventListener` now [accepts an AbortSignal](https://github.com/whatwg/dom/search?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+addEventListener+signal&type=commits) which you can use to remove the event listener when needed.

So in Firefox Nightly (86) and in Chrome Canary(90) you can do

```js
async function mouseDoesSomething() {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    let count = 0;
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const onevent = (evt) => {
      console.log( ++count );
      if( count >= 5 ) {
        resolve();
        controller.abort();
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onevent, { signal: controller.signal } );
    document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onevent, { signal: controller.signal } );
  } );
}
mouseDoesSomething().then( () => console.log('done') );
```

To detect for support you can use the usual property-bag trap:

```js
const support = (() => {
  let support = false;
  const trap = {};
  Object.defineProperty(trap, "signal", { get() { support = true; } } );
  new EventTarget().addEventListener('foo', ()=>{}, trap);
  return support;
})();

console.log( support );
```

Comment: This is really what I was hoping for when I started investigating! It felt really weird to me that I couldn't do something like `event.context.removeSelf()`. Look forward to this being widely available - thanks for sharing :)