# React and Javascript: Equivalent for C function prototypes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function-prototypes

Some experimentation I'm doing with React has gotten me the following code:

```
const BreadNav = props => {
  const initial={
    stack:[
      {
        name:"Home",
        render:React.cloneElement(
          props.children,
          {pushElement:pushElement}
        ),
        state:{}
      }
    ],
  };

  const [state, setState] = React.useState(initial);

  const pushElement = (oldState,elem) => {
    let newStack = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.stack));
    newStack[newStack.length-1].state = oldState;
    newStack.push(elem);
    setState({
      ...state,
      stack:newStack
    });
  }
  
  return(
    state.stack[state.stack.length-1].render
  );
}
```

React gives me `ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'pushElement' before initialization` which makes sense for the order the  lines are in. If this was C, I would just throw in a function prototype to declare `pushElement` and define it later, but I haven't seen a javascript answer for this. How do I avoid this trouble?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a function *declaration*, which is "[hoisted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52880419/1048572)", instead of assigning a function value to a `const` variable:

```
function BreadNav(props) {
  const initial = {
    stack: [
      {
        name: "Home",
        render: React.cloneElement(props.children, {pushElement}),
        state: {}
      }
    ],
  };

  const [state, setState] = React.useState(initial);

  function pushElement(oldState,elem) {
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    let newStack = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.stack));
    newStack[newStack.length-1].state = oldState;
    newStack.push(elem);
    setState({
      ...state,
      stack: newStack
    });
  }
  
  return state.stack[state.stack.length-1].render;
}
```

but in this case it would be much more appropriate to define the function *before* you use it in the `initial` object literal:

```
const BreadNav = props => {
  const pushElement = (oldState, elem) => {
    let newStack = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.stack));
    newStack[newStack.length-1].state = oldState;
    newStack.push(elem);
    setState({
      ...state,
      stack: newStack
    });
  };
  const initial = {
    stack: [
      {
        name: "Home",
        render: React.cloneElement(props.children, {pushElement}),
        state: {}
      }
    ],
  };

  const [state, setState] = React.useState(initial);
  
  return state.stack[state.stack.length-1].render;
}
```

You can still refer to the `state` and `setState` variables declared below, they are in scope, you just must make sure not to call the function before they are initialised.

Comment: This ended up working, I just had misinterpreted a "cyclic object reference" error as being related to this. Thank you.