# Are modules fully "parsed" before they are used in other files?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hoisting

I came across an example in React and I am trying to figure out how and why it works.

```
function MyComponent() {
 return <h2>{name}</h2>
}

const name = "John";

export default MyComponent;
```

And in App.js, we're using this component, nothing fancy.

But I expected embedding name within MyComponent's JSX not to work due to how hoisting behaves with let and const, since they're placed in the TDZ until its declaration is reached.

I also tried a simple example in JavaScript.

```
function myFunc() {
  console.log(name);
}

const name = "John";

export default myFunc;
```

And in my main.js, I import the function and simply execute it. It also works.

Which makes me think that modules go through the creation and execution phase before its content is used in another file? Or am I involving the execution context wrongly here? What's the explanation?

Comment: Modules are fully evaluated when loaded.

Comment: This has nothing to do with modules, though. The code works even outside modules. https://jsbin.com/ximohazoxi/edit?js,console The TDZ is relevant if you try to *use* the identifier before it's declared. If you use it after then it's OK. In my example, the function is called after. In your case ***the export is after***. The entire reason to even have the TDZ is an artefact of making sure the identifier is usable: see [Is there a purpose to hoisting variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52879220)

Comment: @VLAZ Even if I use the export before the variable declaration, it'll still work.

```
function myFunc() {
  console.log(name); // Still works
}

export default myFunc; // I can export function inline aswell, or use named exports, still works

const name = "John";
```

Comment: @kekerinho yes, because all the code in the file has run to completion. When you later use an exported function, its context has been established.

Comment: @Pointy Interesting, could you perhaps provide a link to that statement, so I can read more?

Comment: @kekerinho consider a module had more than one export. How would you expect importing to work? Only execute the module up to the first export? Work until the export you've imported? Isn't that both too much work and extremely inconsistent? I'd think it's self-evident that a deterministic behaviour is expected. Or can you offer a suggestion why it would work randomly and importing might or might not work after a module is refactored?

Answer (score 0):

What matters is the order of execution, not the position in the code:
[MDN "temporal dead zone"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#temporal_dead_zone_tdz)

> The term "temporal" is used because the zone depends on the order of execution (time) rather than the order in which the code is written (position)

Your exact use case is described there as well:

> For example, the code below works because, even though the function that uses the let variable appears before the variable is declared, the function is called outside the TDZ.
>
> ```
> {
>   // TDZ starts at beginning of scope
>   const func = () => console.log(letVar); // OK
>
>   // Within the TDZ letVar access throws `ReferenceError`
>
>   let letVar = 3; // End of TDZ (for letVar)
>   func(); // Called outside TDZ!
> }
> ```

### Modules

[JavaScript modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) are evaluated when the code that imports them is evaluated.

(I like to think of it as if the imported code would simply be put at the location of the `import` statement before everything is executed together, which is not correct, but helps me thinking about it.)

[MDN "export"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#description)

> Export declarations are not subject to temporal dead zone rules. You can declare that the module exports X before the name X itself is declared.
>
> ```
> export { x };
> const x = 1;
> // This works, because `export` is only a declaration, but doesn't
> // utilize the value of `x`.
> ```